# solr-dump and restore from on prem to servers in gcp

Tags: solr, solr8

task is to do a dump and restore of solr from on prem to servers in gcp

For this we got folders from the team as follows
data,conf,core.properties
inside--data---index and logs
inside--conf---solrconfig.xml,managed-schema.xml,params.json  protwords.txt stopwords.txt  synonyms.txt

i created a core in the server(gcp)
added these folders alike locations of other existing cores

but after doing this i am facing an error suddenly which says below
**org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core : Error loading schema resource schema.xml**

please note after checking few resources i renamed the managed-schema.xml to schema.xml

any help is highly appreciated
thanks in advance